# how to build a library (eclipse birt report engne)

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I want to change one variable (MAX_PAGE_BREAK_INTERVAL = 999999 from ListingElementExecutor) in the org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.2.2.v20130216-1152 library.

In order to do that i downloaded the project from here: https://github.com/eclipse/birt.

I manage to modify the value of that variablee. (\engine\org.eclipse.birt.report.engine\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\engine\executor.ListingElementExecutor).

I have jdk 1.8 and mpn 3.5.0.

Now i dont know how to compile this library. According to documentation i need to run this
 `mvn package -DskipTests`, but i see a lot of errors.
I am not a developer. I just need this for BI. Can you sai if there is a way to fix this errors and succesfuly compile this in a jar?

````
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[835]
[ERROR]         public void setTextUnderline( String underline ) throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[843]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[852]
[ERROR]         public void setTextOverline( String overline ) throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[860]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[869]
[ERROR]         public void setTextLineThrough( String through ) throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[877]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[886]
[ERROR]         public void setBackgroundPositionX( String x ) throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[894]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[903]
[ERROR]         public void setBackgroundPositionY( String y ) throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\StyleInstance.java:[911]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\ContentUtil.java:[273]
[ERROR]         return ExpressionUtil.transformConditionalExpression( condExpr );
[ERROR]                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method transformConditionalExpression(IConditionalExpression) from the type ExpressionUtil refers to the missing type IConditionalExpression
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\ContentUtil.java:[291]
[ERROR]         Object value = evaluator.evaluate( expression );
[ERROR]                                  ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method evaluate(String) from the type IBaseResultSet refers to the missing type BirtException
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\ContentUtil.java:[324]
[ERROR]         Object value = evaluator.evaluate( expression );
[ERROR]                                  ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method evaluate(String) from the type IBaseResultSet refers to the missing type BirtException
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\ContentUtil.java:[524]
[ERROR]         return evaluator.evaluate( expHandle.getType( ),
[ERROR]                          ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method evaluate(String, String) from the type IBaseResultSet refers to the missing type BirtException
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\BaseCrosstabExecutor.java:[120]
[ERROR]         IDataQueryDefinition query = context.getQueries( elementHandle )[0];
[ERROR]                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getQueries(Object) from the type IExecutorContext refers to the missing type IDataQueryDefinition
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\BaseCrosstabExecutor.java:[122]
[ERROR]         IBaseResultSet rset = context.executeQuery( getParentResultSet( ),
[ERROR]                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method executeQuery(IBaseResultSet, IDataQueryDefinition, Object) from the type IExecutorContext refers to the missing type IDataQueryDefinition
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\executor\BaseCrosstabExecutor.java:[129]
[ERROR]         cubeCursor = cubeRset.getCubeCursor( );
[ERROR]                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getCubeCursor() from the type ICubeResultSet refers to the missing type CubeCursor
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabExtendedItemFactory.java:[32]
[ERROR]         public IExtendedItem createExtendedItem( ExtendedItemHandle handle )
[ERROR]                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method createExtendedItem(ExtendedItemHandle) of type CrosstabExtendedItemFactory must override or implement a supertype method
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabExtendedItemFactory.java:[55]
[ERROR]         return super.createExtendedItem( handle );
[ERROR]                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method createExtendedItem(ExtendedItemHandle) from the type ExtendedItemFactoryBase refers to the missing type ExtendedItemHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\ICrosstabInstance.java:[75]
[ERROR]         throws ScriptException;
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabCellReportEventHandler.java:[40]
[ERROR]         public void onCreate( IOnCreateEvent event ) throws BirtException
[ERROR]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception BirtException is not compatible with throws clause in ReportEventHandlerBase.onCreate(IOnCreateEvent)
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabCellReportEventHandler.java:[42]
[ERROR]         DesignElementHandle modelHandle = event.getHandle( );
[ERROR]                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getHandle() from the type IReportEvent refers to the missing type DesignElementHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabCellReportEventHandler.java:[65]
[ERROR]         public void onRender( IOnRenderEvent event ) throws BirtException
[ERROR]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception BirtException is not compatible with throws clause in ReportEventHandlerBase.onRender(IOnRenderEvent)
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabCellReportEventHandler.java:[67]
[ERROR]         DesignElementHandle modelHandle = event.getHandle( );
[ERROR]                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getHandle() from the type IReportEvent refers to the missing type DesignElementHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabInstanceImpl.java:[196]
[ERROR]         throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabInstanceImpl.java:[207]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabInstanceImpl.java:[221]
[ERROR]         .getReportDesign( )
[ERROR]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getReportDesign() from the type Report refers to the missing type ReportDesignHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabCellInstanceImpl.java:[80]
[ERROR]         return context.evaluate( ExpressionUtil.createJSDataExpression( bindingName ) );
[ERROR]                        ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method evaluate(String) from the type IReportContext refers to the missing type BirtException
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabCellInstanceImpl.java:[131]
[ERROR]         throws ScriptException
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\CrosstabCellInstanceImpl.java:[144]
[ERROR]         throw new ScriptException( e.getLocalizedMessage( ) );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemQuery.java:[53]
[ERROR]         super.setModelObject( modelHandle );
[ERROR]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method setModelObject(ExtendedItemHandle) from the type ReportItemQueryBase refers to the missing type ExtendedItemHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemQuery.java:[84]
[ERROR]         context.getDataRequestSession( ).getModelAdaptor( ),
[ERROR]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getDataRequestSession() from the type IQueryContext refers to the missing type DataRequestSession
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemQuery.java:[183]
[ERROR]         context.createQuery( parent, handle );
[ERROR]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method createQuery(IDataQueryDefinition, ReportElementHandle) from the type IQueryContext refers to the missing type IDataQueryDefinition
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[40]
[ERROR]         public void prepare( ) throws BirtException
[ERROR]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception BirtException is not compatible with throws clause in ReportItemPreparationBase.prepare()
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[42]
[ERROR]         if ( !( handle instanceof ExtendedItemHandle ) )
[ERROR]                 ^^^^^^
[ERROR] DesignElementHandle cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[47]
[ERROR]         CrosstabReportItemHandle crosstab = (CrosstabReportItemHandle) ( (ExtendedItemHandle) handle )
[ERROR]                                                                                               ^^^^^^
[ERROR] DesignElementHandle cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[56]
[ERROR]         Object hideDetail = handle
[ERROR]                             ^^^^^^
[ERROR] DesignElementHandle cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[92]
[ERROR]         context.evaluate( "1" ); //$NON-NLS-1$
[ERROR]                 ^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method evaluate(String) from the type IReportContext refers to the missing type BirtException
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportItemPreparation.java:[142]
[ERROR]         handle.setProperty(
[ERROR]         ^^^^^^
[ERROR] DesignElementHandle cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportEventHandler.java:[34]
[ERROR]         public void onCreate( IOnCreateEvent event ) throws BirtException
[ERROR]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception BirtException is not compatible with throws clause in ReportEventHandlerBase.onCreate(IOnCreateEvent)
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportEventHandler.java:[36]
[ERROR]         DesignElementHandle modelHandle = event.getHandle( );
[ERROR]                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getHandle() from the type IReportEvent refers to the missing type DesignElementHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportEventHandler.java:[57]
[ERROR]         public void onRender( IOnRenderEvent event ) throws BirtException
[ERROR]                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Exception BirtException is not compatible with throws clause in ReportEventHandlerBase.onRender(IOnRenderEvent)
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\re\CrosstabReportEventHandler.java:[59]
[ERROR]         DesignElementHandle modelHandle = event.getHandle( );
[ERROR]                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method getHandle() from the type IReportEvent refers to the missing type DesignElementHandle
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\ICrosstabCellInstance.java:[41]
[ERROR]         throws ScriptException;
[ERROR]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] No exception of type ScriptException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable
[ERROR] C:\Users\valerica.georgescu\Downloads\birt-master\xtab\org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core\src\org\eclipse\birt\report\item\crosstab\core\script\internal\handler\CrosstabPreparationHandler.java:[199]
[ERROR]         context.prepare( handle );
[ERROR]                 ^^^^^^^
[ERROR] The method prepare(DesignElementHandle) from the type IPreparationContext refers to the missing type DesignElementHandle
[ERROR] 45 problems (45 errors)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.eclipse.birt.report.item.crosstab.core```
````